# Wordpress custom permalinks redirecting posts to root

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My blog url is like `www.example.com/blog` and my posts url is like `https://www.example.com/blog/index.php/postname` and permalinks are set as custom. /index.php/%postname%/

I want to remove blog/index.php for post urls so that post url is `https://www.example.com/post-name`

If I change the permalinks to use custom with `/%postname%/`, it redirects my posts to 404 page.

Any guidance how I can achieve it?

Comment: You'll need to write a custom URL rewrite on your server in `.htaccess` or similar (depending on the server daemon being used).

Comment: Hi @belinus Thanks for reply. I already tried .htaccess. It was actually because of my server, nginx that doesnt process .htccess. Its solved now.